# Установка yii2 + base template на локальный компьютер Linux/ubuntu

Tags: php, yii2

Никогда не имел дело с фреймворком `yii2`. Скачал весь сайт по фтп + база к нему.

Файлы скинул в `/var/www/html` - однако ничеого не заработало.
При переходе на `localhost/index.php` - выхлоп ошибки.
Подключение к бд сделал вроде правильно.
Есть ли какие либо нюансы при портировании сайта на `yii2` на локальную машину?
Выхлоп

```
//exit();

//Main config file with all settings and autoloads
require_once "config/autoload.php";

//Set 1 to see the work time and sql queries
$debug = new Debug(0); 

//Main object of site also contains all modules objects
$mv = new Builder();

$products_delete = isset($_SESSION['shop']['cart']) && $_SESSION['shop']['cart'] ? $_SESSION['shop']['cart'] : "";

if ($products_delete && is_array($products_delete))
{
    $products_delete = $mv -> products -> select(array("id->in" => implode(",",array_keys($products_delete))));
    $mv -> cart -> deleteProducts($products_delete);
}

//Router refers to include needed view to display the page
include_once $mv -> router -> defineRoute();

//If 1 was passed above, displays the data
$debug -> displayInfo($mv -> router);
```

Comment: Так какие ошибки?

Comment: Помимо описание ошибки, лучше бы детально описали пошагово то, что делали. Откуда качали, настраивали `htaccess`, делали ли `init`, и прочее

Comment: Выхлоп указал, но не думаю что он чем то поможет. Причем, такой выхлоп был до того как я базу поставил.

Comment: Там же корневая папка web. Вы точно все правильно прописали?

Comment: в yii корневая папка web?? или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: Еще раз повторю - опишите лучше все шаги установки. Есть ли папка `vendor`? есть ли в папке `web` вообще что-то? как настроен виртульный хост в апаче? как настроены `htaccess`? Как я понимаю этот "выхлоп" в виде цветной таблицы выводится. Можно заскринить и приложить фото......лучше кидать не в `var/www/html` а `var/www/yourDomain` и настроить и виртуальный хост, а не по `localhost` обращаться

Comment: это код страницы с выхлопом. виртуального хоста нет. папки вендор нет. в папке web файлы сайта, скаченного по фтп. апач не настраивал - поставил, обычный index.php работает. Походу тут не так все просто как я думал.

Comment: Конечно. Вы скачали базовый шаблон. А сам фреймворк в папке `vendor`, которой у вас нет) чтоб она появилась кажется надо `init` сделать, а еще лучше все делать через `composer`. как в мануале написано.....откуда вы что качали? по каким мануалам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, вам следует почитать документацию о том, как настроить виртуальный хост в Линуксе. Любой виртуальный хост. А только после этого пытаться примерять фреймворки и прочее))

Попробую описать под `Ubuntu 14.04` как это сделать.

- Бежим вот сюда:http://www.yiiframework.com/download/#yii2 качаем `Yii 2 with basic application template` - это базовый шаблон с папкой `vendor`(сам фремворк)
- Идем в папку `/var/www` создаем директорию, к примеру `yii2-app` и в нее кидаем все, что находится в скачанной папке `yii-basic-app-2.0.7/basic`.
  В итоге в `/var/www/yii2-app` должны находится папки assets,config,vendor, web и прочее
- Идем в `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` и добавляем (если нет таких строк):

  ```
  ServerName localhost    
  ## Для того, чтобы Apache интерпретировал php и не предлагал сохранить php-файл
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml

  ## Установка кодировки UTF-8 по умолчанию
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  #
  ```
- Идем в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` создаем конфигурационный файл `yii2-app.conf`, прописываем в него то, что под спойлером:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName yii2-app
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/yii2-app

  <Directory /var/www/yii2-app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
 ErrorLog /var/www/yii2-app/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/yii2-app/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- Создаем паку `logs` в папке `/var/www/yii2-app` и файлы  `error.log` и `access.log`
- Теперь надо включить сайт `sites-enabled`.... для этого просто создаем сим линк конфига из `sites-available`.... Для этого в терминале можно написать:
  `ln -s откуда_копируем куда_копируем`. В нашем случае это:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/yii2-app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yii2-app.conf
  ```
- Открываем файл `/etc/hosts`, прописываем

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  127.0.0.1   yii2-app
  ```
- Открываем терминал, включаем `mod rewrite` апачу и перезапускаем его:

  ```
  sudo a2enmod rewrite
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

Как минимум уже по адресу `http://yii2-app` должны появится папки. Если нет - значит надо настроить права у папок. Очень опасно, но можно выполнить в консоли `chmod 777 /var/www/yii2-app -R` что позволит читать и писать и выполнять все файлы всем кому не лень. **Так делать нельзя!** Хоть и увидите свои папки. Просто это для демонстрации того, что все появилось и надо лишь настроить права для папок.

- В `/var/www/yii2-app/config/web.php` необходимо задать значение для ключа `cookieValidationKey`

И по крайней мере по адресу `http://yii2-app/web` уже будет что-то видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целом нужно еще файлы `.htaccess`

Один `.htaccess` в корне `/var/www/yii2-app` с настройками:
    
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

И один `.htaccess` в папке `/var/www/yii2-app/web` с содержимым:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

И уже остальное настраивать в конфигурационных файлах... Должно работать

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite - после этой команды апач перестал подыматься.
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2812] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations     [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2812] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: А нет - это я баран, спасибо большое за начальный гайд. Он очень помог мне.

Answer (score 0):

В Yii2 корневая папка - web. 
А у вас корневая сайта  **/var/www/html**. Изменить на  **/var/www/html/web**

Пример привел для Basic приложения. Но суть не меняется.

Comment: ничего не изменилось, но спасибо за инфу - буду знать.

Comment: давай решать проблему. Скинь скрин ошибки пожалуйста.