# Развертывание проекта на Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer

Доброго всем! Клонировал реп с битбакета(приложение на yii2), выполнил из директории проекта composer install, затем composer update. Появилась папка vendor, вроде всё хорошо. Проверяю локалхост - "Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Сайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение."
Сервер перезапускал, ошибки в логах апаче смотрел, ошибок нет. То есть мне даже не показываются эксепшины Yii, сам сайт не работает. Плюс ко всему, пытался развернуть на работе, используя Убунту + пакет LAMP и дома на винде + xampp. Аналогичная ошибка что там, что там. 
Буду рад любым советам.
Но если вы совсем добряк, можете посмотреть, в чем проблема. Вот архив с проектом http://muonium.rgho.st/69bP2Lp4j.
На битбакете приватный репозиторий компании.
Благославить буду того, кто поможет. Добра всем!

Comment: а вы по правильному пути ищете сайт? Сайт должен лежать где-то тут: `localhost/web/index.php`

Comment: Может это вам поможет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512995/191482