# Yii2 видны публичные каталоги сайта

Tags: yii2

Есть сайт [desavir.ru](https://desavir.ru) написанный на фреймворке Yii2.
Ошибка заключается в том, что при при в вводе в адресную строку название контроллера (например admin,master или user. Пример: [desavir.ru/user](https://desavir.ru/user/)) видны публичные каталоги которые подключаются через AssetBundle.

Конфигурация UrlManager такая:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'post/page/<page:\d+>' => 'post/index',
                'post/' => 'post/index',
            ],
            'normalizer' => [
                'class' => yii\web\UrlNormalizer::class,
            ],
        ],
```

Как избавиться от этого недочета, что бы при переходе по подобному формату ссылки сразу перекидывало на index?

Comment: htaccess надо настроить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512995/191482

Comment: [Что написать в .htaccess и конфиг yii2 basic для дефолтной маршрутизации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517860/191482)