# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "..." not found in

Tags: php, ооп

Помогите пожалуйста новичку. Поставил фреймворк Yii2. Перенес свои файлы в директорию и не получается использовать ни свои классы, ни классы фреймворка. Скриншот composer, ошибка и файлы классов прикрепляю. Перешарил весь англо и русско язычный интернет. Не смог найти информации, которая бы помогла. При подключении класса напрямую командой `require DIR . '/../models/Test.php';` скрипт работает. Не работает настройка автозагрузчика

Тестируемый класс:

[image: Тестируемый класс]

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

class Test
{
    public function PrintHello () {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Тестируемый скрипт:

[image: Тестируемый скрипт]

```
<?php
use app\models\Test;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$obj = new Test;

var_dump($obj->PrintHello());
```

Сценарий автозагрузчика:

[image: Сценарий автозагрузчика]

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "taskforce\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

Код ошибки:

[image: Код ошибки]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "app\models\Test" not found in C:\Applications\OSPanel\domains\taskforce\src\index.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Applications\OSPanel\domains\taskforce\src\index.php on line 6
```

UPD: пишу, возможно как даун, зато как есть. Как я все делаю: создал класс, в нем указал неймспейс, написал метод. Далее создаю тестовый сценарий, там в первой строке(очевидно, кроме строки открытия файла) подключаю автозагрузчик, далее создаю новый экземпляр класс и через вар дамп пишу его метод. Строку use автозагрузчик прописывает автоматически, ее я не трогаю.
UPD 2.0: Свои классы в папке src я заставил работать. Сложность была в том, что в нейспейсе моих классов было `taskforce/src/ClassName`, а надо было просто `taskforce`. Классовую структуру фреймворка так пока и не могу заставить работать

Comment: Не приводите код кортинкой, пожалуйста!

Comment: Понял, исправлю. Прошу прощения

Comment: И ещё там у меня правка висит, примите её.

Comment: так вы файл загрузчика подключаете позже use

Comment: Я когда добавляю новый класс в сценарий. Строчка use автоматические прописывается выше функции require. Если переставляю вручную файл автозагрузчика выше чем use, ошибка остается

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то неймспейс в данном случае должен начинаться не с `app`, а с `taskforce`

Comment: А если в композере поменять `taskforce` на `app` и сделать на всякий случай `composer dump-autoload`  то заработает и с `app`

Comment: А не, стоп...... а почему models и contollers находятся в корне, а actions в src??  как-то разрозненно...... тогда получается будет отчасти вот так `"psr-4": {
          "app\\": "/"
        }`  .... крч, структура странная и приложение должно быть в src (index.php может быть и наружи)

Comment: Для профилактики, для начала запустите `composer dump-autoload`. Пробуем запустить. 
Если не помогло, то гадать тут нечего, нужно узнать где скрипт пытается искать файлы классов. Тут дебаг в помощь. Заходим в  метод класса `ClassLoader::loadClass` (`./vendor/composer`),
добавляем туда `var_dump($class)`. Таким же образом распечатываем еще и то, что  происходит в методе, который оттуда вызывается - `ClassLoader::findFile`.
Пробуем запустить еще раз и смотрим, что выводится в консоль. Сразу станет понятно какой файл и где система пытается найти. Удачи

Comment: Файловая структура создалась сама при установке пакета Yii2 Basic, из того что я добавил - это только в корень поместил папку 'src' со своими файлами

Comment: Если это yii2 basic,  то там никакие  "taskforce\\": "src/" и вообще автолоды не надо писать... оно уже работает и так без него...и есть файл web/index.php в котором уже всё подключение прописано

Comment: по yii2  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512995/191482  и  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517860/191482

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто принял участие. Отдельное спасибо @АлексейШиманский. Переделал файл composer.json . Убрал свои неймспейсы. Переделал всем классам неймспейс на app/../..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не работал в Yii, но судя по всему в вашем psr-4 указан один namespace, а реально используется другой. Т.е composer не знает где искать ваш namespace `app`. Файл конфигурации composer'a находится в той же директории что и весь код, что немного необычно, но тем не менее, означает, что текущая директория и является этим namespace, что и нужно указать в конфигурации.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "."
    }
},
```

посоветовал бы использовать заглавные буквы в названии namespace'ов, что является общепринятой практикой.

Если не заработает, то шаги по дебагу я указал в комментарии к вопросу